# Zend_Form decorators: Unable to view error messages (validation) 

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

When we add decorators to the form elements in zend, the validation message doesn't shows why ?

Code Example :

```
$this->addElement('Text', 'Last_Name',array(
        //'decorators' => $this->elementDecoratorsTr,
        'label' => 'Last Name:',
        'required' => false,
        'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
            'validators' => array(array('validator' => 'StringLength','validator' => 'Alpha')) 
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `Zend_Form_Element` source code:

```
$decorators = $this->getDecorators();
if (empty($decorators)) {
    $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
        ->addDecorator('Errors')   // notice Errors decorator
        ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description'))
        ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 
                                        'id'  => $this->getName() . '-element'))
        ->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'));
}
```

If you set your own decorators then the default ones are not loaded.

In order to see validation messages you need to have an `Errors` decorator among the decorators you set.

Comment: Hi ainokna, yes... I had no errors decorator in my own Decorators.... now i had added errors decorator & its working... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is and example for setting decorators for error msg:

We have element in the :

```
$title = $this->createElement('text', 'title');
    $title->setRequired(true)
        ->setLabel('Title:')
        ->setDecorators(FormDecorators::$simpleElementDecorators)
        ->setAttrib('maxlength', $validationConfig->form->title->maxlength)
        ->addValidator('stringLength', false, array($validationConfig->form->title->minlength,
                $validationConfig->form->title->maxlength,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'messages' => array(
                    Zend_Validate_StringLength::INVALID =>
                    'Title must be between %min% and %max% characters',
                    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>
                    'Title cannot contain more than %max% characters',
                    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>
                    'Title must contain more than %min% characters')));                     
    $this->addElement($title);
```

and this is class with form decorators, you can do a lot of them there:

```
 class FormDecorators {
    public static $simpleElementDecorators = array(
        array('ViewHelper'),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'requiredPrefix' => '<span class="required">* </span>')),
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'desc-item')),
        array('Errors', array('class' => 'errors')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-item'))
    );
    }
```